# Solving for the particular solution of a system of differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP

$\vec{y}'= \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\vec{y} + \begin{bmatrix}t \\e^{2t}\end{bmatrix}$

$\vec{y}(0) = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$

The complementary solution of the linear system $\vec{y}′=Ay$ is

$\vec{y}_C(t)= \begin{bmatrix}e^{-t} & -e^t\\e^{-t} & e^t\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}c_1 \\c_2\end{bmatrix}$

The particular solution is supposed to appear thusly

$\vec{y}_P(t) = \vec{a}e^{2t}+\vec{b}t+\vec{c}$

$\vec{y}_P(t)$ is supposed to appear as a $2 \times 1$ vector.

I tried to look at the system as two separate equations, but because of the initial $A$ matrix something like

$y'_1+y_2 = t$

$y'_2 + y_1 = e^{2t}$

I tried plugging in the supposed particular solution and the derivative as well, but this is confusing because there are separate $a_1$ and $a_2$ values and such that I can't combine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does the first line of $\LaTeX$ even mean?

Comment: Sorry, I totally flubbed the writing there, I just edited it

Answer (score 1):

Plugging the Ansatz $\vec ae^{2t}+\vec bt+\vec c$ in the equation, we have

$$2\vec ae^{2t}+\vec b=M(\vec ae^{2t}+\vec bt+\vec c)+(t,e^{2t})^T.$$

By identification,

$$2\vec a=M\vec a+(0,1)^T,\\0=M\vec b+(1,0),\\\vec b=M\vec c.$$

In other words,

$$\vec a=(2I-M)^{-1}(0,1)^T,\\\vec b=-M^{-1}(1,0),\\\vec c=M^{-1}\vec b.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have a linear system

$$\dot y = A y + u$$

with initial condition $y (0) = y_0$. What you call the complementary solution is what is usually known as the homogeneous solution, or, *natural response*. We now assume zero initial conditions and look for the *forced response*. Laplace-transforming both sides, we get

$$s Y(s) = A Y (s) + U (s)$$

Hence,

$$Y (s) = (s I_2 - A)^{-1} U(s) = \dfrac{1}{s^2 - 1} \begin{bmatrix} s & -1\\ -1 & s\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{s^2}\\ \frac{1}{s-2}\end{bmatrix}$$

Now compute $Y (s)$ and then find the inverse Laplace transform of its two entries. Use a table of Laplace transforms, not the definition.

Comment: Hmm... My professor hasn't gone over Laplace transformations with us and I don't think she will (it wasn't on the list of topics that will be covered on the final). Thanks for your help though

Comment: @J.S.R. Then take a look at the homogeneous solution, and look for a particular solution of the form $$\begin{bmatrix}e^{-t} & -e^t\\e^{-t} & e^t\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \kappa_1 (t) \\ \kappa_2 (t) \end{bmatrix}$$You should get $$\begin{bmatrix}e^{-t} & -e^t\\e^{-t} & e^t\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \dot\kappa_1 (t) \\ \dot\kappa_2 (t) \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} t\\ e^{2t} \end{bmatrix}$$which is a linear system in $ \dot\kappa_1$ and $ \dot\kappa_2$. Solve it, then integrate.

Comment: Is that dot notation the same as $k_1'(t)$?

Comment: @J.S.R. Yes, indeed.

Comment: I'm trying to take the eigenvalues of that $2 \times 2$ matrix at the bottom their but it doesn't turn into a good function since the middle terms do not combine.

Comment: I have for the characteristic equation, $r^2 - re^{-t}-re^t+2=0$ (using r instead of lambda here)

Comment: @J.S.R. You don't need the eigenvalues to do Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Oh, I see now, I have to augment the matrix and row-reduce, thank you

Comment: @J.S.R. You don't need the RREF either. Upper triangular is enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40526/discussion-between-j-s-r-and-rodrigo-de-azevedo).

Answer (score 0):

Try variation of parameters. You already have $y_h(t) = Y(t)c$ as a solution to the homogeneous equation. So, look for a solution to the inhomogeneous equation in the form $y_p(t) = Y(t)c(t)$.

Let $y' = Ay + g$ be the original equation. Then, substituting our proposed solution:

$$ \begin{align*}
(Yc)' &= A(Yc) + g \\
Y'c + Yc' &= (AY)c + g \\
Y'c + Yc' &= Y'c + g \\
Yc' &= g \\
c' &= Y^{-1}g \\
c &= \int Y^{-1}g
\end{align*} $$

Because $Y$ is a fundamental matrix, it is guaranteed to be invertible, so we have found a particular solution to the inhomogeneous equation

$$ y_p = Y\int Y^{-1}g  $$

or, substituting in the given values,

$$ y_p(t) = \\ \begin{bmatrix}\exp -t & -\exp t \\ \exp -t & \exp t\end{bmatrix} \int \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\exp t & \exp t \\ -\exp -t & \exp -t\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}t  \\ \exp 2t \end{bmatrix} \text dt$$

After some simplification, you should get something like

$$ y_p(t) = \begin{bmatrix} -1 - \frac{1}{3}\exp 2t \\ t + \frac{2}{3}\exp 2t \end{bmatrix} $$

which you can add to your homogeneous solution to get a general solution $y = y_h + y_p$, and apply the initial conditions to resolve the unknown constant.